# Pipe Closed Exception with BufferedWriter

Tags: java

I am using BufferedWriter to write on the external Process. In fact I am getting the BufferedWriter from the ProcessBuilder itself.

As it is a continuous process, I am giving this writer to a separate thread and writing few commands. I am not closing the writer since I require that for subsequent calls.

Now it is writing perfectly for the first time but failing for every subsequent time saying Pipe Is Closed exception.

Code snippet is below

```
public SolverWriter(BufferedWriter writer, List<String> commands) {
    this.bWriter = writer;
    this.commands = commands;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        for (String str : commands) {
            // writer.write(str.getBytes());
            // writer.flush();
            bWriter.write(str);
        }
        bWriter.write(RETURN);
        bWriter.newLine();
        bWriter.flush();
        // notifyAll();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any idea how the stream is getting closed when I am not calling any close method?

Comment: I suppose the reading process closes the pipe.

Comment: @laune +1 @OP: BTW this should have nothing to do with `BufferedWriter`. Please try again with a normal `Writer`. If it has the same problem, then the `Buffered` part is a red herring and should be removed from the question.

Comment: The stream isn't getting closed. The *pipe,* to the external process, is getting closed. By the external process.

Comment: Tried with Writer but the problem persists. Any idea how to keep the external process alive. By the way I am not exclusively closing the external process anywhere.

Comment: the external process will be alive as long as you keep it. are you sure you are sending proper commands to it? seems to me that your commands caused the external program to crash

Comment: These two line  bWriter.write(RETURN);
            bWriter.newLine(); I am using to send an equivalent command of Return key. Is it is the cause? If I don't pass these two lines, the program hangs in want of EOF and keeps waiting

Comment: I guess the above mentioned two lines are the culprit. It in fact might be closing the pipe or sending an exit command. The RETURN above is a string variable for \\h